# Error de sintaxis en Postgresql en java

Tags: java, postgresql

tengo dos tablas detalleguardarfactura,guardarfactura y quiero crear una vista de algunas de las columnas de guardarfactura el problema es que se me presenta un error de sintaxis que no puedo solucionar 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
String SQL4 = "INSERT INTO DetalleGuardarFactura (NombreFactura,cliente_nombrecliente,FechaFacturaGuardada,estado)"
                + " values (?,?,?,?)";
        ps = Conexion.prepareStatement(SQL4);
        ps.setString(1, nombre);
        ps.setString(2, CamposCliente[2].getText());
        ps.setTimestamp(3, timestamp);
        ps.setBoolean(4, true);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        for (int i = 0; i < Modelo.getRowCount(); i++) {
            if (Modelo.getValueAt(i, 0) == Boolean.TRUE) {
                String SQL2 = "INSERT INTO guardarfactura (NumeroParte,NombreRepuesto"
                        + " ,PrecioUnitario,TotalGanacia,CantidadRepuesto,DetalleGuardarFactura_NombreFactura,Estado)"
                        + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                ps = Conexion.prepareStatement(SQL2);
                ps.setString(1, (String) Modelo.getValueAt(i, 3));
                ps.setString(2, (String) Modelo.getValueAt(i, 2));
                /////////////////////////////////////
                Object id = Modelo.getValueAt(i, 4);
                String ide = id.toString();
                Double valor = Double.parseDouble(ide);
                ps.setDouble(3, valor);
                /////////////////////////////////////
                Object id2 = Modelo.getValueAt(i, 5);
                String ide2 = id2.toString();
                Double valor2 = Double.parseDouble(ide2);
                ps.setDouble(4, valor2);
                ////////////////////////////////////
                Object id3 = Modelo.getValueAt(i, 4);
                String ide3 = id3.toString();
                int valor3 = Integer.parseInt(ide3);
                ps.setInt(5, valor3);
                ps.setString(6, nombre);
                ps.setBoolean(7, true);
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        String SQL3 = "create view ? as SELECT NumeroParte,NombreRepuesto"
                + " ,PrecioUnitario,TotalGanacia,CantidadRepuesto"
                + " from guardarfactura WHERE DetalleGuardarFactura_NombreFactura=? and estado=?";
        ps = Conexion.prepareStatement(SQL3);
        ps.setString(1, nombre);
        ps.setString(2, nombre);
        ps.setBoolean(3, true);
        ps.executeUpdate();
```

Ingrese en postgres y me inserta las dos tablas pero la vista no me la crea, ahí esta el error y verifico pero no encuentro el error, espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: `create view ? as SELECT NumeroParte,NombreRepuesto` esta sentencia viola la filosofía de las consultas preparadas, las cuales han sido creadas para pasar en parámetros los valores de las **columnas**, y **NO para pasar en parámetros nombres de tabla o vista**, porque además ¿qué sentido tiene hacer que el servidor de BD adivine el nombre de la vista? ¿por qué no ponérselo directamente en lugar del signo `?`...? Las consultas preparadas son para proteger el código de inyección SQL separando los valores que se envía de la instrucción SQL.

Comment: @A.Cedano como hago entonces?

Comment: No he probado a crear una `VIEW` usando prepared statement porque en realidad creo que no tiene sentido. Si pruebas poniendo el nombre de la vista en lugar del `?` quizá funcione, no lo sé: `create view nombreVista as SELECT...` mi pregunta es, ¿por qué no haces el `SELECT` directamente? sin verte obligado a tener que crear una vista. Una vista en el fondo es una representación de una o varias tablas que ya existen.

Comment: @A.Cedano tienes razón, no tiene sentido muchas gracias

Comment: De nada. Puedes considerar el borrar la pregunta o bien aceptar una respuesta indicando como solución el uso inadecuado de nombres de vistas/tablas como parámetros en un preparedstatement (comentario 1).

Comment: Efrain, en realidad lo mejor es publicar una respuesta. Evita borrar una pregunta cuyo contenido es valioso para el sitio.